# How do you use IMPORTXML correctly?

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

I just started using ImportXML in Google sheets, although I have been successfully using it several times, this time I can't figure out what is going wrong:

I want to scrape the monthly visitors of a website through similarweb. Here is an example URL:
`https://www.similarweb.com/website/autohuset-vestergaard.dk/#overview` 
Copying the Xpath results in:

`//*[@id="overview"]/div/div/div/div[5]/div/div[1]/p[2]`

The formula I'm using is:

`=IMPORTXML("https://www.similarweb.com/website/autohuset-vestergaard.dk/#overview";"//*[@id='overview']//div/div/div/div[5]/div/div[1]/p[2]")`

And I get a #N/A error

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Make sure that your XPath is valid. Try running your XPath query in the Chrome console using $x(). When I do this, I get a warning that the expression isn't valid. Perhaps try adding a `*` after the opening set of slashes?

Comment: Thanks. I have no idea how to makes sure that the Xpath is valid. What I do now is right click the element I'm interested in and simply 'copy Xpath'. Is there a different way? Adding the ''' * ''' is not helping, but what does this do anyway?

Comment: Edit: checked the path using console, but no result in sheet. `$x("//*[@id='overview']//div/div/div/div[5]/div/div[1]/p[2]")
[p.engagement-list__item-value]
0: p.engagement-list__item-value
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)`

Comment: So, that eliminates one issue. When you mouse over the #N/A text, do you see an error message?

Comment: yes, value cannot be retrieved from the URL

Comment: I tried a few things to sort of what might be going on. First, I looked at the robots.txt file - and the path wasn't expressly forbidden. Next, I looked at the headers using the Chrome dev tools and didn't see any particular issue. Lastly, I tried grabbing the page using `curl` and what I got back was a page with a captcha challenge. It may just be that you can't scrape similarweb in this way. Perhaps try the SimilarWeb API:  https://docs.api.similarweb.com/